# Eigenvalues of $A$ and $A + A^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

This question has popped up at me several times in my research in differential equations and other areas:

Let $A$ be a real $N \times N$ matrix.  How are the eigenvalues of $A$ and $A + A^T$ related?
Of course, if $A$ is symmetric, the answer is easy:  they are the same up to factor or $2$, since then $A + A^T = 2A$.  But if $A \ne A^T$?

I'm particularly interested in the question of the real parts of the eigenvalues.  How are the real parts of the eigenvalues of $A$ related to the (necessarily) real eigenvalues of $A + A^T$?

Answers for complex matrices appreciated as well.

Any references, citings, or explanations at any level of detail will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If $A$ is diagonalizable, then $\rho(A + A^T) \leq \rho(A) + \rho(A^T) = 2 \rho(A)$, where $\rho$ is the radius (equal to the matrix norm for $A$ diagonalizable).

Comment: @Eric Auld:  yes, of course; the challenging part comes when $A$ is not real-diagonalizable, so the real Jordan form has blocks like $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$ etc.

Comment: I don't think there's much you can say about the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ solely in terms of those of $A$. For example, consider $A = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\lambda&t\\0&\mu\end{array}\right)$ where $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are fixed, and $t$ is a real parameter. So the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\lambda$ and $\mu$. Using the quadratic formula you can check that the eigenvalues of $A+A^T$ are $\lambda+\mu \pm \sqrt{(\lambda-\mu)^2+t^2}$ which depend on $t$ and not just $\lambda$ and $\mu$.

Comment: @RobertLewis In response to your comment , I was wondering in case when $A$ is not real diagonalizable, is it always possible to transform $A$ into a structure $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\{-b} & a\end{bmatrix}$? In extension to that, should an even order matrix will always be transformed into a matrix with each diagonal block having structure $\begin{bmatrix}a & b\\{-b} & a\end{bmatrix}$.

Comment: @jbgujgu:  No, but a $2 \times 2$ real matrix will transform either to $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{bmatrix}$ or $\begin{bmatrix} a & b \\ 0 & a \end{bmatrix}$.  This is Jordan canonical form stuff.  Cheers!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This question was answered [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/97733/), see also comments to its ["closed-as-duplicate" post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116170/), especially ones by Terry Tao.

Here is Tao's comment from, now deleted, post [2](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/116170/):

"Note that if A is strictly upper triangular, then its eigenvalues are all zero, whereas $A+A^T$ is an arbitrary symmetric matrix with zero diagonal, which constrains the trace of the matrix but otherwise imposes almost no conditions on the spectrum whatsoever (the only other constraint I can see is that the matrix cannot be rank one). So, apart from the trace $tr(A+A^T)=2tr(A)$, there appears to be essentially no relationship."

Comment: The closed post has been deleted.

Comment: I'm acepting this answer since I have learned a lot from the references an it has been around long enough to be "ripe", as it were.  But I do *not* think the last word has been said.  I have been thinking of posting a seperate, reformulated version, but I am currently struggling with a backlog of about sixty answers-in-preparation, and they bug me.  Anyway, thanks for the helpful remarks.  Holiday Cheers to one and all!

Comment: @Studiosus:  and a separate word of gratitude to you, good sir!  Cheers!

Answer (score 14):

EDIT: Let $\lambda\in spectrum(A)$; then there is $\mu \in spectrum(A+A^T)$ s.t. $|\lambda-\mu|\leq ||A||_2$ (spectral norm).

Proof: Since $A+A^T$ is real symmetric, according to the Bauer–Fike Theorem, there is $\mu\in spectrum(A+A^T)$ s.t. $|\lambda-\mu|\leq ||-A^T||_2=||A||_2$. cf. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bauer%E2%80%93Fike_theorem

Comment: Wow!  Very nice; useful *and* interesting!  Thanks so much!  Yul Tov!  As you can see from my pic on my user page, I am Santa's brother!  I'll put in a good word, so watch your stocking!  Salud!

Answer (score 1):

A special case is when $A$ is a unitary matrix: eigenvalues of $A$ lie on unit circle in complex plane. If $e^{i\theta}$ is an eigenvalue of $A$, then $2 \cos(\theta)$ is an eigenvalue of $A + A^T$. Similarly, $2i\sin(\theta)$ is an eigenvalue of $A - A^T$.