# $M$ is row strict diagonally dominant matrix and Hurwitz. What about $M+M^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, control-theory, stability-theory

Consider a row strict diagonally dominant matrix $M$ such that:

$$\begin{cases}
m_{i,i} < 0 ~\forall i\\
m_{i,j} \geq 0 ~\forall j \neq i\\
\displaystyle \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N m_{i,j} < -m_{i,i} ~\forall i.
\end{cases}.$$

Of course, all eigenvalues of $M$ have negative real part.

Now consider the matrix $P = M + M^T.$

Can I conclude that also all the eigenvalues of $P$ are negative?

Intuition (and optimism) says me "yes". But I need a result that assures that the claim is right.

I found very few stuff googling around about the spectrum of the sum of matrix with its transpose. I only found [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/453700/eigenvalues-of-a-and-a-at) on MathSE. But it refer to  a generic matrix $M$.

Comment: Doesn't your third inequality contradict diagonal dominance?

Comment: @darijgrinberg $M$ is diagonally dominant if $\displaystyle \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N |m_{i,j}| < |m_{i,i}| \Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{j=1, j \neq i}^N m_{i,j} < -m_{i,i},$ no?

Comment: Ah. Our definitions of "diagonally dominant" differ (mine has no absolute value around the $m_{i,i}$).

Comment: Diagonally dominant should have only one definition. @the_candyman is right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is NOT true. I will give you a counterexample:
$M=\begin{bmatrix}-1.01 & 1 \\2& -2.01 \end{bmatrix}, P=M+M^T=\begin{bmatrix}-2.02 & 3 \\3 & -4.02 \end{bmatrix}$.

Using matlab command *eig* I found out that the eigenvalues of $M$ are $-0.01$ and $-3.01$ while those of $P$ are $-6.1823$ and $0.1423$. It is noted that $M$ is strictly diagonally dominant and Hurwitz as requried in the question. However, the second eigenvalue of $P$ is positive and therefore proves that your proposition is false. Actually, there are many counterexamples to this questions.

BTW:
The definitions of **diagonally dominant** and **strictly diagonally dominant** are as follows [*]:

> A matrix $A=[a_{ij}]\in M_n$ is diagonally dominant if 
>   \begin{equation} |a_{ij}| \ge \sum_{j \ne i}|a_{ij}|=R_i^{'} ~~for~all
> > ~i=1,..,n \end{equation} It is strictly diagonally dominant if 
>   \begin{equation} |a_{ij}| > \sum_{j \ne i}|a_{ij}|=R_i^{'} ~~for~all
> > ~i=1,..,n \end{equation}

Base on this, your question is not accurate enough. You should change the condition to **strictly diagonally dominant** instead.

[*]: Horn, Roger A., and Charles R. Johnson. Matrix analysis. Cambridge university press, 2012.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer, It has been very helpful for me. I'm going to fix my answer (strict diagonally dominant) for the future interested users.